# failure in installing tensorflow whl for python 3.6

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have been getting the following error trying to install tensorflow using pip (don't use Anaconda) on windows 10 64-bit. I have python 3.6 on my machine

> tensorflow-1.2.1-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on
>   this platform.

Does it install only through conda?

Comment: You can just run `pip install tensorflow`.

Comment: Based on this link: https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_windows, TensorFlow only supports version 3.5.x of Python on Windows.

Comment: @MiriamFarber works fine for me and I run 3.6.1

Comment: @MLavrentyev interesting! Is this a "formal" wheel? (that is, created by tensorflow official team or something like that?) I wonder why they didn't mention that on their website.

Comment: @MiriamFarber not sure - I just ran the pip command above. Also according to PyPi, there is a wheel for 3.6 https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tensorflow/1.3.0rc0 They likely just didn't update their website yet.

Comment: @MLavrentyev thanks for the information :)

Comment: @MLavrentyev probably should have mentioned upfront: I tried 'pip install tensorflow-1.2.1-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl'. That's when I got that error. Running 'pip install tensorflow' throws the error, ' Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for tensorflow'

Comment: Do you have numpy installed?

Comment: Yes. Plus pandas, scipy, sklearn, pyplot, matplotlib, tflearn -- just in case any of that can cause conflicts.