# How can I install TensorFlow from packages manually downloaded from https://pypi.org/simple/*?

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip, pycharm

I am trying to install [TensorFlow](https://www.tensorflow.org/) on Windows using Anaconda, behind a firewall.

None of the attempts

**[--trusted-host](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39680454/9295807)**

```
pip install tensorflow --trusted-host pypi.python.org
```

**[conda create](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_windows)**

```
conda create -n tensorflow pip python=3.6
activate tensorflow
pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade tensorflow
```

or **[--no-cache-dir](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4806458/9295807)**

```
pip install tensorflow --no-cache-dir
```

let me install tensorflow using Anaconda on Windows.

The problem has to do with access permissions

```
> pip -v install tensorflow
...
* https://pypi.python.org/simple/tensorflow/
...
Starting new HTTPS connection (1): pypi.python.org
...
'NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at ..>:
Failed to establish a new connection:
[WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target
machine actively refused it',)': /simple/tensorflow/
...
```

Weirdly, I can download the whl file just fine, but [afterwards](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27909082/9295807)

```
pip -v install tensorflow-1.10.0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl

Processing c:\...\tensorflow-1.10.0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl
```

tells me that

```
Collecting grpcio>=1.8.6 (from tensorflow==1.10.0)
1 location(s) to search for versions of grpcio:
* https://pypi.python.org/simple/grpcio/
```

So I figure I'll install the recursively needed packages manually, starting with grpcio, but neither the most recent

```
pip -v install grpcio-1.14.1-cp36-cp36m-win32.whl

pip.exceptions.InstallationError: grpcio-1.14.1-cp36-cp36m-win32.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
```

nor the oldest possible needed by this version of tensorflow

```
pip -v install grpcio-1.8.6-cp36-cp36m-win32.whl

pip.exceptions.InstallationError: grpcio-1.8.6-cp36-cp36m-win32.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
```

will install.

I am able to download from `https://pypi.org/simple/*` just fine. How do I use the downloaded packages to install tensorflow?

```
Conda 4.3.27
Python 3.6.2
Windows 7 Pro
```

**Update 1**

After the first steps of the [recipe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51862175/9295807)

- Download tensorflow-1.10.0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl from pypi.org/simple
- Put the whl file in c:/Users/vrok/.conda/envs
- `activate c:/Users/vrok/.conda/envs/`

the fourth

```
conda install tensorflow-1.10.0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl
```

fails with

```
CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED for url
<https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/main/win-64/repodata.json.bz2>
```

even though I am able to download `https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/main/win-64/repodata.json.bz2` manually.

**Update 2:**

I'm not tied to Anaconda. Any option on Windows is good. PyCharm, IIUC, hooks on to a prior installation. It does not provide python/pip/venvs itself. Still, in Settings \ Project \ Project Interpreter, the user is not told which URL was unreachable. Knowing this would enable those behind firewalls to open, or request opening, access to specific URLs.

**Related:**

[one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14277088/9295807), [two](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45422607/9295807)

Comment: It looks like your platform is `win_amd64`. Why did you download `grpcio` for `win32` then? I see `grpcio-1.14.1-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl` on PyPI, you should install that instead.

Comment: If you can't resolve the issue with your firewall/proxy to be able to download wheels directly with `pip`, I'd suggest to download them from another machine not having the firewall problem: `pip download --platform win_amd64 --implementation cp --python-version 36 --abi cp36m --only-binary=:all: --dest packages tensorflow` will download `tensorflow` and all dependencies recursively for your platform. Then copy the `packages` dir to your machine and install from it: `pip install tensorflow --find-links packages/`.

Answer (score 0):

Why you haven't tried the obvious?

```
conda install -n myenv tensorflow=[your version here or leave blank for latest]
```

or you can do it the more interactive way:

```
activate [your environment]
conda install [your thing]
```

Then you can test your installation with

```
conda list
```

Comment: Although, it's recommended to use the `pip` way of installing as described on tensorflow's website; [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_windows)

Comment: That's a good path, but I couldn't get that through. I updated the question with my attempt of your solution.

Comment: Sorry if that couldn't help